# Do these 2 sql queries return the same result?

Tags: sql

```
select c1, c2 from t1
where not exists
(
select 1 from t2
where t1.c2 = t2.c3
)
```

and

```
select c1, c2 from t1
where c2 not in 
(
select c3 from t2
)
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it out?

Comment: @Lieven: "just try it out" only applies if you're lucky enough to have data on hand that covers all the possible cases (and, of course, if you know what all the possible cases are).

Comment: @mu is too short - true but it is not that there are that many possible cases. Just using NULL and 1 for c1 and c2 and NULL and 1 for c3 alread covers most of them. 4 inserts into t1, 2 into t2.

Comment: @onedaywhen: False, on some DBMS, if column c3 contains NULL values, NOT IN(NULL) will work, on some other, not !

Comment: @Arnaud-f Only SQL Server with `ANSI_NULLS OFF` that I know of. Are there others?

Comment: @Arnaud: NOT IN (NULL) should not return a row in *any* DBMS. I would be interested in knowing which DBMS fails to comply with that?

Comment: They are both ways, among others, of writing semi difference (a.k.a. anti join) in SQL. Sure you get different results with the non-relational null value but caveat emptor ;)

Answer (score 5):

#### No, they are not the same. The difference is in how NULL values are treated.

- `not exists` returns records where `c2` equals `NULL`
- `not in` does **not** return records where `c2` equals `NULL`

#### Test script

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (c1 INTEGER, c2 INTEGER)
DECLARE @t2 TABLE (c3 INTEGER)

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (NULL, NULL), (1, NULL), (NULL, 1), (1, 1)
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES (NULL), (1)


select c1, c2 from @t1 t1
where not exists
(
  select 1 from @t2 t2
  where t1.c2 = t2.c3
) -- returns (NULL, NULL) & (1, NULL)


select c1, c2 from @t1
where c2 not in 
(
  select c3 from @t2
) -- returns nothing
```

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.

I guess the right query to use will be based on whether I need null values in my result.

Comment: @Anil: I think it will depend on whether null values exist in the tables you are semijoining, rather than the resultset.